# Windows VDI can't start virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have a remote desktop deployment. All of my users have been running for a few days with no issues. Then this morning a single user was not able to connect through RDWeb or RDC. The user gets the error

```
Couldn't connect to the remote computer (there was a problem setting up the virtual machine)
```

So I went and started the machine through Hyper-V. The virtual machine starts normally. So I checked into the logs and the only error I see is

```
Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed while getting redirection packet from Connection Broker.
```

My current set up is pretty straight forward. RDWeb, RD Gateway, Connection Broker and Virt-Host are all installed on a dedicated Windows server 2012. I don't have this problem with any other users. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Just in case I wanted to throw you this . . . **[`Somehow we missed the Gp setting: Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Remote Desktop Services / Remote Desktop Session Host / RD Connection Broker / Use RD Connection Broker load balancing . Changed from Disabled to Enabled and gpupdate / force on RD session hosts put the trouble away !`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/48f2358a-7d9f-4db3-b540-d47670bc729f/problem-with-remote-desktop-connection-broker?forum=winserverTS)**

Comment: Thanks you, but no dice. I checked that as well. I did find a work around. I had to create a new virtual machine for the user and all was well. I'm still curious where this issues comes from. I hope someone has some insight for next time.